# White Screen appears for some time upon opening keyboard in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Upon clicking on TextInput, a white screen is shown for some milliseconds and then the keyboard pops up and it also shifts the content upwards.
Is there any way to make the keyboard stop resizing the application on the keyboard open? Isn't there a way to make the keyboard slide up and down on the app as an overlay and there will be no resizing required like giving a div zIndex of 100 to make it stand above all

Sample code:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        //....
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          behavior={'height'}
          style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "black" }}
        >
          <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20, justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center" }}>
            <TextInput placeholder="Enter Text" style={{backgroundColor:"red", padding: 20 }}/>
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

react-native: 0.71
I'm using Expo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using softwareKeyboardLayoutMode: "pan" in app.json fixed my issue.

app.json

```
{
  "expo": {
    "android": {
      // other properties
      "softwareKeyboardLayoutMode": "pan",
    }
  }
}
```